# TightVNC over VPN encrypted?

Tags: vpn, cisco-asa, vnc

I'm using tightvnc to connect to my servers over a IPSEC VPN connection with split tunneling enabled.

Is my communication with my servers via VNC encrypted or unencrypted?

Comment: Does the VNC connection work when the VPN is down?

Comment: Good question. I am connecting to my servers via their internal 192.168.x.x IP, so I doubt it would work.

Answer (score 3):

Communications between your machine and the VPN endpoint are encrypted.  That includes the VNC connection.

However, once the packets reach the remote network, the VNC communications between the servers and the VPN endpoint are not encrypted.  TightVNC only encrypts passwords, not traffic (as per http://www.tightvnc.com/faq.php).

Comment: can you source this?

Comment: @ton.yeung Sure.  I added a link to the TightVNC FAQ in the answer.  IPsec is encrypted by definition.

Comment: Sorry, I meant how the VNC connection will go through the VPN connection and so will therefor be encrypted. What concerns me is that I have split tunneling turned on. Traffic to the internet will still go through my local gateway, right? I'm concerned that somehow, that compromises my VNC connection somehow.

Comment: @ton.yeung You mentioned in a comment above that you're connecting to your servers via addresses in the 192.168.0.0/16 netblock.  Those addresses aren't routable over the Internet, so they should be going through your VPN connection.

Comment: @ton.yeung If you want to check exactly what's going on, check the routing table on your computer.  The gateway for the 192.168.x.x route should be provided by your VPN endpoint.